# Convert GBK to utf8 string in python

Tags: python, utf-8, gbk

I have a string.

```
s = u"<script language=javascript>alert('\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
```

How can I translate `s` into a utf-8 string? I have tried `s.decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')` but python reports error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 35-50: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: When you add `u` your string is already being treated as an unicode string by python.

Comment: I know it's a unicode string. But I cann't print it out.

Answer (score 6):

in python2, try this to convert your unicode string:

```
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('gbk')
u"<script language=javascript>alert('\u8bf7\u8f93\u5165\u6b63\u786e\u9a8c\u8bc1\u7801,\u8c22\u8c22!');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
```

then you can encode to utf-8 as you wish.

```
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')
"<script language=javascript>alert('\xe8\xaf\xb7\xe8\xbe\x93\xe5\x85\xa5\xe6\xad\xa3\xe7\xa1\xae\xe9\xaa\x8c\xe8\xaf\x81\xe7\xa0\x81,\xe8\xb0\xa2\xe8\xb0\xa2!');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
```

Comment: The detour over `latin-1` is shocking.  Yes, it's a workaround, but that is really not how you do it.

Comment: @tripleee not shocking at all once you know the mechanics behind it. Unicode used Latin-1 as its base for the first 256 codepoints, so if you need those codepoints as bytes it's a 1:1 mapping. Obviously it's better to get the decoding done properly in the first place, but sometimes with [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) that's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing apples and oranges.  The GBK-encoded string is not a Unicode string and should hence not end up in a `u'...'` string.

This is the correct way to do it in Python 2.

```
g = '\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,' \
    '\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!'.decode('gbk')
s = u"<script language=javascript>alert(" + g + 
    u");location='index.asp';</script></script>"
```

Notice how the initializer for `g` which is passed to `.decode('gbk')` is not represented as a Unicode string, but as a plain byte string.

See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep the alert in a separate string "a":

```
a = '\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!'.decode("gbk")
s = u"<script language=javascript>alert('"+a+"');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
print s
```

Then it will print:

```
<script language=javascript>alert('请输入正确验证码,谢谢!');location='index.asp';</script></script>
```

If you want to automatically extract the substring in one go:

```
s = "<script language=javascript>alert('\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
s = unicode("'".join((s.decode("gbk").split("'",2))))
print s
```

will print:

```
 <script language=javascript>alert('请输入正确验证码,谢谢!');location='index.asp';</script></script>
```

Comment: @amazingjxq: In the second method pay attention, that the string s is plain, not s=u''.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) but I think one way to do this is:

```
import unicodedata

s = u"<script language=javascript>alert('\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!');location='index.asp';</script></script>"
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('utf-8','ignore')
```

Comment: Could down-voter please explain why he/she down-voted so I can learn too? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same question

Like this:

> name = u'\xb9\xc5\xbd\xa3\xc6\xe6\xcc\xb7'

I want convert to

> u'\u53e4\u5251\u5947\u8c2d'

Here is my solution:

> new_name = name.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('gbk')

And I tried yours

> s = u"alert('\xc7\xeb\xca\xe4\xc8\xeb\xd5\xfd\xc8\xb7\xd1\xe9\xd6\xa4\xc2\xeb,\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb!');location='index.asp';"
>
> print s
>
> alert('ÇëÊäÈëÕýÈ·ÑéÖ¤Âë,Ð»Ð»!');location='index.asp';

Then:

> _s = s.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('gbk')
>
> print _s
>
> alert('请输入正确验证码,谢谢!');location='index.asp';

Hope can help you ..