# python encoding chinese to special character

Tags: python, decode, encode

I have scrape/curl request to get html from other site, that have chinese language but some text result is weird, it showing like this:

> °¢Àï°Í°ÍÎªÄúÌá¹©ÁË×ÔÁµÕß¹¤³§Ö±ÏúÆ·ÅÆµç×Ó±í ÖÇÄÜÊ±ÉÐ³±Á÷Å®Ê¿ÊÖ»·ÊÖÁ´Ê×ÊÎ±í´øµÈ²úÆ·£¬ÕâÀïÔÆ¼¯ÁËÖÚ¶àµÄ¹©Ó¦ÉÌ£¬²É¹ºÉÌ£¬ÖÆÔìÉÌ¡£ÓûÁË½â¸ü¶à×ÔÁµÕß¹¤³§Ö±ÏúÆ·ÅÆµç×Ó±í ÖÇÄÜÊ±ÉÐ³±Á÷Å®Ê¿ÊÖ»·ÊÖÁ´Ê×ÊÎ±í´øÐÅÏ¢£¬Çë·ÃÎÊ°¢Àï°Í°ÍÅú·¢Íø£¡

that should be in chinese language, and this is my code:

```
str(result.decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

If without decode 'ISO-8859-1' (only return **result** variable) it will display question mark like this:

> ����Ͱ�Ϊ���ṩ�������߹���ֱ��Ʒ�Ƶ��ӱ� ����ʱ�г���Ůʿ�ֻ��������α����Ȳ�Ʒ�������Ƽ����ڶ�Ĺ�Ӧ�̣��ɹ��̣������̡����˽���������߹���ֱ��Ʒ�Ƶ��ӱ� ����ʱ�г���Ůʿ�ֻ��������α�����Ϣ������ʰ���Ͱ���������

Could you help me which encode/decode that I should use?

Thanks

Comment: You should check what kind of encoding the website is using. You can check the "content-type" variable in HTTP header to see if they have "encoding=" value. And use that to decode. And what happens when you decode with "iso-8859-1"? Does it display correctly?

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I see header result displaying as text/html;charset=GBK, when I use iso-8859-1 it displaying like the first result above °¢Àï°Í°ÍÎªÄúÌá¹©ÁË×ÔÁµÕß¹¤xxx

Comment: If it's GBK, then you should try this [convert-gbk-to-utf8-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103485/convert-gbk-to-utf8-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple solution, as mentioned by @Thu Yein tun, to see the header response of the http request link for the content type, and I it showing as text/html;charset=GBK,
then I give the solution to my code like this

```
result.decode('gbk')
```

Answer (score 1):

Chinese has several possible charsets.
3 common chinese charsets are: gb2312,big5 and gbk.
Here is a snippet to convert from `gb2312` to `utf-8`.

```
import codecs

infile = codecs.open("in.txt", "r", "gb2312")
lines = infile.readline()
infile.close()

print(lines)

outfile = codecs.open("out.txt", "wb", "utf-8")
outfile.writelines(lines)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code.

You can do by importing the `unquote` file & encode the content using `latin1` encoding mechanism.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib2 import unquote

bytesquoted = u'å%8f°å%8d%97 è¦ªå­%90é¤%90å»³'.encode('latin1')
unquoted = unquote(bytesquoted)
print unquoted.decode('utf8')
```

**Output :**

台南 親子餐廳

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` in the end of line, https://trinket.io/python/63e1aef683

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the answer provided by @Usman above. For Python 3.x you may do this:

```
import urllib

bytesquoted = u'å%8f°å%8d%97 è¦ªå­%90é¤%90å»³'.encode('latin1')
print(urllib.parse.unquote(bytesquoted)) #'台南 親子餐廳'
```

This should work for you.

Reference: [Python: Importing urllib.quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827012/python-importing-urllib-quote)