# Python Webscraping: Problems parsing chinese characters with beautiful soup/requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am scraping a Chinese website and usually there is no problem to parse the chinese characters which i use to find specific urls with the pattern function within bs4.
However, for this particular chinese website the soup cannot be parsed properly.
Below is the code i use to set up the soup:

```
start = f'http://www.shuichan.cc/news_list.asp?action=&c_id=93&s_id=210&page={1}'
r = requests.get(start)
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
```

An example of the printed soup is the following:

[Current soup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfdu.png)

Note: I had to add a picture as Stack though it was spam :)

The above should have looked like the following:

[Proper soup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuZXi.png)

I wonder if i have to specify some kind of encoding within the request or perhaps something within the soup but as for now i have not found anything that would work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Chinese. Does this give the desired results?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

start = f'http://www.shuichan.cc/news_list.asp?action=&c_id=93&s_id=210&page={1}'
r = requests.get(start)
soup = bs(r.content.decode('GBK', 'ignore'), "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

Comment: Yes it does - Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the fix does?

Comment: it's just the character set for the site. Just need to encode it. Can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954604/python-encoding-chinese-to-special-character)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for scraping a Chinese language website.  Thanks.